# What is the difference between /usr/local/bin & /usr/local/sbin

Tags: linux, directory

I wrote a simple script which I want to share with my colleagues.

Should it be in /usr/local/bin or /usr/local/sbin? What is the typical usage for these directories?

Answer (score 21):

/usr/local/bin is for programs that a normal user may run.

/usr/local/sbin is for system administration programs (which are not part of the core OS) that a local administrator may run. By default, a normal user does not have /usr/local/sbin on their path.

Answer (score 12):

The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard answers this: https://www.pathname.com/fhs/.